# What's the expected damage from playing Terror of the Peaks, when I have Mirror March out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, probability

If I play [Terror of the Peaks](https://scryfall.com/card/m21/164/terror-of-the-peaks) while I control
[Mirror March](https://scryfall.com/card/rna/108/mirror-march), what is the expected damage? That is the average of winning 1, 2, 3, ... 'Infinity' flips? I'm sure it's a converging sum, but I'm not sure how to work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this:

The first Terror (the one you cast) comes out, the March triggers, but not the Terror. The March resolves, and you flip coins, getting N heads, meaning N Terrors enter the battlefield. Including the one already there, they all see all the others enter the battlefield, see rule 603.6a (emphasis mine):

> 603.6a Enters-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent enters the battlefield. These are 
>   written, “When [this object] enters the battlefield, . . . “ or “Whenever a [type] enters the 
>   battlefield, . . .” Each time an event puts one or more permanents onto the battlefield, **all 
>   permanents** on the battlefield (**including the newcomers**) are checked for any enters-the-
>   battlefield triggers that match the event.

So that's one Terror that deals damage N times, and N Terrors that each deal damage (N-1) times, for a total of 5*N^2 damage.

The probability distribution of N (assuming a fair coin) is given by

> P(N=n)=2^(-n)

By definition of expectation, the expected damage dealt is therefore:

> P(N=0)*5*0^2 + P(N=1)*5*1^2 + P(N=2)*5*2^2 + ...

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5E%28-n%29*5n%5E2%2C+n+from+0+to+inf), this comes out to be 30.

If you want to know how to actually get 30 from this, [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask for the details. I'd be happy to answer it for you over there, as would many others I'm sure (as long as you stick to our guidelines for a good question). It's a lot easier to write math there as well.

Comment: The fact that they all see each other enter at the same time makes this much simpler than I imagined.

Comment: @Pureferret It makes it a bit simpler, but not much. Instead of 5N^2, you would've gotten 2.5N^2+2.5N (triangular numbers rather than squares). The math after that is almost the same, you just have to do the final sum twice, once for the P(N=n)*2.5n^2 terms, and once for the P(N=n)*2.5n terms.

Comment: I would have thought that it'd have involved factorials?

Comment: @Pureferret Well, it doesn't. No permutations here, just exponential probability and a squared damage term.

Comment: While this answer is entirely correct, it's also misleading if you're planning a deck based on it, because while the expected value of the damage is 30, the odds of killing your opponent (from 20 life) are only 25%, and your odds of getting nothing at all are 50%

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The question asked was about expected damage. No one said anything about killing someone. Maybe you want to deal damage to creatures, or to multiple players. Or maybe it's commander, and expected damage of 30 there is not as misleading about how often you can expect to kill someone.